# Why has this UnpicklingError occurred?

Tags: python, pickle

One one file, I have written:

```
import pickle
with open('pickle test2.py', 'wb') as p:
    var = {1: "a", 2: "b"}
    pickle.dump(var, p)
```

On another ('pickle test.py') the pickled version of the var dict is being stored.

And on a separate file I have attempted to load this dict, but an UnpicklingError has occurred. I wrote:

```
import pickle
with open('pickle test2.py', 'rb') as p:
    var = pickle.load(p)
```

This was the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Nathan/Python/pickle test open.py", line 4, in <module>
    var = pickle.load(p)
_pickle.UnpicklingError
```

What does this mean, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: I'd not use the `.py` extension here for the filename. You could accidentally end up trying to run the pickle, or vice versa, trying to load a Python script as a pickle. Perhaps the latter is what happened.

Comment: The code is otherwise entirely correct. Why you got a pickle error then depends entirely on what happened with the file between the two scripts.

Comment: Another issue I can see is that you are using relative path names, which means that the directory where this file is looked up depends on the current working directory (`import os; print(os.getcwd())`). Depending on how you run your Python scripts, the current working directory could be somewhere entirely different. If there is a `pickle test2.py` file in a different location that isn't a valid pickle file, you'd also get this error.

Comment: can you change file name and check again. It is working for me with `file name .py`

Comment: can you add all you code from `pickle test open.py` file?

Comment: That works! Thanks you.

Comment: The question displays all of the code I wrote in the files.

Comment: what was issue because your code is working at my end?

Comment: I changed the file name that I was storing the pickled version of the var dict to, to 'file name.py'.

Comment: It works now, but there may have been an issue with the current working directory.